# React SPA throws CORS error with oAuth2 on /token call

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I created react App with with proxy setup in package.json and there was no CORS error on API request from local and deployed server. However now I implemented oAuth2 in my application which throws CORS error when /token API is hit.

I see since proxy works only on local system and APIs being hit directly when application is deployed on EC2, why it needed separate configuration for oAuth2.

Could anyone suggest if there is any other configuration needed to address this specific to oAuth2 server as my application server requests serve well with configuration made in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Which OAuth2 Server are you using? Usually there is an option to configure CORS - see [step 7 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/) for an example.

Comment: yes there are some configuration changes needed like you mentioned in your  post.